# Using a for in loop within a for in loop with a calendar

Tags: jquery, json, momentjs

I am trying to create a clean way to create an advent calendar. The logic is this:

Using moment.js to compare times, if todays date is equal to a date in a json array then add a class giving it a green "door" which will allow you to click on it and then a slide effect to reveal what is underneath the blurred green door. If not add a class that makes it a red "door" and if that is clicked, prompt a message saying check back tomorrow.

I have it working if I code out each day separately. But that is ugly and not efficient. But perhaps that is my only way? Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7D3t2/6/)

HTML:

```
<div class="week clearfix">
<div class="day " id="day1">
    <div class="header">Day 1</div>
    <div class="door" id="door1"></div>
    <div class="blur" id="blur1">So maybe you could start jete-ing, and stop je-terrorizing me!</div>
    <div class="content" id="content1">So maybe you could start jete-ing, and stop je-terrorizing me!</div>
</div>
<div class="day " id="day2">
    <div class="header">Day 2</div>
    <div class="door" id="door2"></div>
    <div class="blur" id="blur2">It feels good to be back in a queen! It's Sunday, but screw it — juice box time. And I am rock steady. No more dizzies. And here you are coming out of your mother's third base! Can't a guy call his mother pretty without it seeming strange? Amen. And how about that little piece of tail on her? Cute!</div>
    <div class="content" id="content2">It feels good to be back in a queen! It's Sunday, but screw it — juice box time. And I am rock steady. No more dizzies. And here you are coming out of your mother's third base! Can't a guy call his mother pretty without it seeming strange? Amen. And how about that little piece of tail on her? Cute!</div>
</div>
<div class="day " id="day3">
    <div class="header">Day 3</div>
    <div class="door" id="door3"></div>
    <div class="blur" id="blur3">
        <img src="http://kyleledbetter.com/silo-3/assets/images/avatars/george-michael_128.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="content" id="content3">
        <img src="http://kyleledbetter.com/silo-3/assets/images/avatars/george-michael_128.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="day " id="day4">
    <div class="header">Day 4</div>
    <div class="door" id="door4"></div>
    <div class="blur" id="blur4">And I wouldn't just lie there, if that's what you're thinking. that's not what I WAS thinking. Look at us, crying like a couple of girls on the last day of camp. Everything they do is so dramatic and flamboyant. It just makes me want to set myself on fire. Did Ted make an appointment?</div>
    <div class="content" id="content4">And I wouldn't just lie there, if that's what you're thinking. that's not what I WAS thinking. Look at us, crying like a couple of girls on the last day of camp. Everything they do is so dramatic and flamboyant. It just makes me want to set myself on fire. Did Ted make an appointment?</div>
</div>
<div class="day " id="day5">
    <div class="header">Day 5</div>
    <div class="door" id="door5"></div>
    <div class="blur" id="blur5">I am getting rid of this thing. It has caused me nothing but pride and self-respect. Stop licking my hand, you horse's ass. He… she… what's the difference? Oh hear, hear. In the dark, it all looks the same. Early. Butterscotch! Want a lick? there's unlimited juice? this party is gonna be off the hook.</div>
    <div class="content" id="content5">I am getting rid of this thing. It has caused me nothing but pride and self-respect. Stop licking my hand, you horse's ass. He… she… what's the difference? Oh hear, hear. In the dark, it all looks the same. Early. Butterscotch! Want a lick? there's unlimited juice? this party is gonna be off the hook.</div>
</div>
<div class="day " id="day6">
    <div class="header">Day 6</div>
    <div class="door" id="door6"></div>
    <div class="blur" id="blur6">Even it means me taking a chubby… I will suck it up. Oh, yeah, the guy in the the $4,000 suit is holding the elevator for a guy who doesn't make that in three months. Come on! Even though sooooo many people in this office are begging for it.</div>
    <div class="content" id="content6">Even it means me taking a chubby… I will suck it up. Oh, yeah, the guy in the the $4,000 suit is holding the elevator for a guy who doesn't make that in three months. Come on! Even though sooooo many people in this office are begging for it.</div>
</div>
<div class="day " id="day7">
    <div class="header">Day 7</div>
    <div class="door" id="door7"></div>
    <div class="blur" id="blur7">In the mid '90s, Tobias formed a folk music band with Lindsay and Maebe which he called Dr. Funke's 100 Percent Natural Good Time Family Band Solution.</div>
    <div class="content" id="content7">In the mid '90s, Tobias formed a folk music band with Lindsay and Maebe which he called Dr. Funke's 100 Percent Natural Good Time Family Band Solution.</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
var n;
var days;
var today = moment();
var days = {
    "day1": moment([2014, 5, 22]),
        "day2": moment([2014, 5, 23]),
        "day3": moment([2014, 5, 24]),
        "day4": moment([2014, 5, 25]),
        "day5": moment([2014, 5, 26]),
        "day6": moment([2014, 5, 27]),
        "day7": moment([2014, 5, 28])
};
var numbers = {
    1: 1,
    2: 2,
    3: 3,
    4: 4,
    5: 5,
    6: 6,
    7: 7
};

for (d in days) {
    console.log(d);

    for (n in numbers) {
        var dn = days[d].diff(today, 'days');
        if (dn <= 0) {
            console.log("#door" + [n]);
            $("#door" + [n]).addClass("avb");
            $("#day" + [n]).click(function () {
                $("#door" + [n], "#blur" + [n]).slideUp("slow", function () {
                    $("#content" + [n]).fadeIn("slow");
                });
            });
        } else {
            $("#door" + [n]).addClass("notavb");
            $("#day" + [n]).click(function () {
                $("#shadowbg").fadeIn("slow", function () {});
            });
        };
    };
};
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to create a reusable jquery plugin that can be used to turn any combination of 7 DIVs with content into such a calendar. By using momentjs powerful features you can make it dynamic and locale-aware.
`I have created a JSFiddle example that you could use as a starting point:` http://jsfiddle.net/dKk6H/13/